# Reference of the polynomials satisfying $f(t+u, v)+f(t,u)=f(u+v, t)+f(u,v)$.

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-groups

Are there some reference of the polynomials satisfying $f(t+u, v)+f(t,u)=f(u+v, t)+f(u,v)$? I would like to know some of there properties. I am asking this question because these polynomials appear in the book Linear algebraic groups by Springer (page 51). Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe $f(t+u, v)+f(t,u)=f(t,u+v)+f(u,v)$?

Comment: @BorisNovikov, thank you very much. The polynomial satisfies $f(t+u,v)+f(t,u)=f(u+v,t)+f(u,v)$. If we assume that $f$ is homogeneous, then $f(u,0)=f(0,u)=0$. Hence $f(u,v)=f(v,u)$. Then the equation will be the same as your equation. Have you seen this equation somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the equation of a 2-cocycle.

Comment: thank you very much. Could you give more references?

Comment: You can find this in any book in Homological algebra, where cohomology of groups is considered (e.g., K.Brown, Cohomology of Groups). In the simpliest case (which is enough for your situation) let $G$ be a group, $A$ an Abelian group. A map $f:G\times G\to A$ is called a 2-cocycle if $f(y,z)-f(xy,z)+f(x,yz)-f(x,y)=0$ for ALL $x,y,z\in G$. Honestly, I don't understand this place in the book by  Springer: he says about cocycle, but the equation must be fulfilled for all elements of the additive group generated by $t,u,v$.